# How can I have multiple Collection Views in one View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want one View Controller to have seven horizontal button scrolls. I've set up the first Collection View, and I repeated the exact process for a second Collection View directly underneath, but I keep getting Thread 1: SIGABRT error. My code for the functional Collection View is here:

```
class xyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var tableImages: [String] = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Initialize the collection views, set the desired frames
}   
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableImages.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:xyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! xyCollectionViewCell

    cell.xyImgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}   

}
```

It works when I run this.

So when I add a second Collection View underneath, create a new View Controller file to IBOutlet the button's image and a new Collection View Cell file to add the following code, it crashes.

```
class bwViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var bwTableImages: [String] = ["a", "PlasmaBlast.png", "b.png", "c.png", "d.png", "e.png", "f.png", "g.png", "h.png", "i.png", "j.png"]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return bwTableImages.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell:bwCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! bwCollectionViewCell

cell.bwImgCell.image = UIImage(named: bwTableImages[indexPath.row])

return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
println("cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using multiple sections? Does that cover your use case? Each Section in a UICollectionView can have it's own header and footer too.

Comment: Not quite sure how to use multiple sections. Google search hasn't been very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a two-section version of the code you wrote. I'm not sure if it addresses the error you are seeing, but it's how you'd do multiple collection views on one page.

```
class xyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var tableImagesOne: [String] = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png"]
    var tableImagesTwo: [String] = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Initialize the collection views, set the desired frames
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return tableImagesOne.count
        }
        else {
            return tableImagesTwo.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let section = indexPath.section

        let cell:xyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! xyCollectionViewCell

        if section == 0 {
            cell.xyImgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImagesOne[row])
        }
        else if section == 1 {
            cell.xyImgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImagesTwo[row])
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("cell \(indexPath.section) : \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }   

}
```